# How to Handle Dynamic Changing IDs inside a span

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

How to Handle Dynamic Changing IDs inside a span In XPath? for example :

```
  <span id="listv2_f40a0e90dbcc089cae10d48a489619ee_total_rows" style="margin-left: 1px;">2000</span>
```

In this xpath id value "f40a0e90dbcc089cae10d48a489619ee" is changing every time when reloading the page.

Is there any way to handle this type of situation in Selenium? Below is the outer HMTL , where I need to extract the text  **2000** present in **total_rows**

```
<div class="vcr_controls">
    <input aria-label="Skip to row" id="listv2_f40a0e90dbcc089cae10d48a489619ee_first_row" aria-describedby="f40a0e90dbcc089cae10d48a489619ee_description_of_skip_to" class="list_row_number_input form-control  " autocomplete="off" title="" style="color:rgb(72, 85, 99); display:inline; height:21px" disabled="" data-original-title="Skip to row">
        <span class="sr-only" id="f40a0e90dbcc089cae10d48a489619ee_description_of_skip_to">Showing rows 1 to 1 of 1</span>
        <span style="margin-left: 5px;" class=" list_row_number_input ">
                    to
            <span id="listv2_f40a0e90dbcc089cae10d48a489619ee_last_row" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px">1</span>
                    of
            <span id="listv2_f40a0e90dbcc089cae10d48a489619ee_total_rows" style="margin-left: 1px;">2000</span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "*total_rows" is unique and constant - I think this should work to get to the span:

> "//span[contains(@id, 'total_rows')]"

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //span[contains(@id,'total_rows')] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Verify that the xpath is ok first - go to the web page with the element, open console and do (in chrome): $x("//span[contains(@id, 'total_rows')]")
If this works it's not a locator issue - see if the element is hidden behind something in the test or try increasing wait time for the element to load

Comment: yes i was able to locate the XPath in console,                          $x("//span[contains(@id, 'total_rows')]")
(4) [span#listv2_98a4a6fe1b88c49011ef337cdc4bcb44_total_rows, span#98a4a6fe1b88c49011ef337cdc4bcb44_rep_total_rows, span#listv2_94a4a6fe1b88c49011ef337cdc4bcb45_total_rows, span#94a4a6fe1b88c49011ef337cdc4bcb45_rep_total_rows],tried increasing the time out to 40 seconds and even 60 seconds but still no luck

Comment: Ah, so the "total_rows" is not unique. Try pointing to the correct one with an index - "(//span[contains(@id, 'total_rows')])[2]" If the correct one remains and is still not clickable, your problem is not the selector anymore. tho It's not a really good solution - as soon as something will be added this will probably break.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the unique string from attribute value and use xpath

`//span[contains(@attribute, 'unique string')]`

Comment: `code` WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'total_rows')]")));
   String ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'total_rows')]")).getText();
   System.out.println(ele);                                                                                         **bold**org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //span[contains(@id,'total_rows')] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)